# unable to post data from google form (multiple pages) using Android

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-docs-api, google-forms

We are trying to post the Google form data from android using a single page and found no issue & working fine but when I do it for the Google form having multi pages, the code doesn't work & not showing any errors & data is also not posting in the response spreadsheet. Request your help or suggestions on resolving this issue.

Given below the spreadsheet link and the form link for your reference, please feel free to use.

This is my Spreadsheet Link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AlGBFkawforcAXR52lgOofZpTrbifc6oR9_vzon-xng/edit?usp=sharing

This is my Form Link :  https://docs.google.com/a/rentokil-initial.com/forms/d/1XLDeGG1dPB9LgBwGV7a3u6Iy_REkHPA861j2-wiEqFI/formResponse

Coding that I use :

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final String myTag = "DocsUpload";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Log.i(myTag, "OnCreate()");
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
postData();

}
});
t.start();
}



public void postData() {

String fullUrl = "https://docs.google.com/a/rentokil-initial.com/forms/d/1XLDeGG1dPB9LgBwGV7a3u6Iy_REkHPA861j2-wiEqFI/formResponse";
HttpRequest mReq = new HttpRequest();
String col1 = "Hello";
String col2 = "World";

String data = "entry_1235143921=" + URLEncoder.encode(col1) + "&" + // Page 1 Column 1
"entry_751142178=" + URLEncoder.encode(col2)+ "&" + // Page 1 Column 2
"entry_894977691=" + URLEncoder.encode(col2)+ "&" + //next steps
"entry_1847757769=" + URLEncoder.encode(col2)+ "&" + // Page 2 Column 1
"entry_1650249198=" + URLEncoder.encode(col2)+ "&" + // Page 2 Column 2
"entry_867489656=" + URLEncoder.encode(col2)+ "&" + // Next Steps
"entry_415944417=" + URLEncoder.encode(col2); // Page 3 Email Option
String response = mReq.sendPost(fullUrl, data);
Log.i(myTag, response);
} 

} </i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the source code of the last page of your form pre-filled with the pre-fill URL. You will see all the input values necessary to submit such a form.

For example, I have a 5-pages Google form and POST parameters to to sumbit it are (URL encoding omitted):

```
draftResponse=[[[,1259094821,["a"] ,0] ,[,1569349418,["b"] ,0] ,[,761878587,["c"] ,0] ,
[,1449369153,["d"] ,0] ,[,1969838782,["e"] ,0] ,[,512061352,["f"] ,0] ,[,1130777548,["g"] ,0] ,
[,1891422103,["h"] ,0] ,[,1443488775,["i"] ,0] ,[,334575825,["j"] ,0] ,[,1194435682,["k"] ,0] ,
[,1553967934,["l"] ,0] ,[,790515093,["m"] ,0] ,[,239587371,["n"] ,0] ,[,1156880365,["o"] ,0] ,
[,345605363,["p"] ,0] ,[,1094543521,["q"] ,0] ,[,1426090282,["r"] ,0] ,[,1405610105,["s"] ,0] ,
[,818780182,["t"] ,0] ] ,,]&pageHistory=1,2,3,4,5&submit=Submit
```